# Javascript iterative highlight

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I am trying to have the code below always highlight var s2 with colors from the color array that I have. On the first iteration, I want it to color var s2 with "DarkSalmon", on the second iteration, I want it to color var s2 with "ForestGreen" and so on. It is not doing that for some reason. Someone please help me out. What am I missing here?

```
var text =  obj[0].srcLanguageSentence.text;

var strArry = [];  
var colorArr = ["DarkSalmon", "ForestGreen", "Brown"];
for(var i=0; i<obj[0].srcLanguageSentence.roles.length; i++)
{

    // create variables representing substrings of the Source language Sentence
    var s1 = text.substring((obj[i].srcLanguageSentence.roles[i].beginOffset - obj[i].srcLanguageSentence.roles[i].beginOffset),(obj[i].srcLanguageSentence.roles[i].beginOffset - 1));
    var s2 = text.substring(obj[i].srcLanguageSentence.roles[i].beginOffset,obj[i].srcLanguageSentence.roles[i].endOffset);
    var s3 = text.substring(obj[i].srcLanguageSentence.roles[i].endOffset,obj[i].srcLanguageSentence.text.length);

    strArry.push('<h4>'+s1+'</h4>')
    //strArry.push('<h4>'+'<font color='"+colorArr[i]+"'>"+s2+'</font>'+'</h4>')

    if(i == obj[0].srcLanguageSentence.roles.length-1)
    {
        strArry.push('<h4>'+s3+'</h4>');
    }

    text =  s3;
}
```

Comment: you're not using `colorArr` anywhere, you have it commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got errors in this part.

```
strArry.push('<h4>'+'<font color="'+colorArr[i]+'">"'+s2+'</font>'+'</h4>');
```

Also, I'm assuming these are node you're going to append to the DOM.